# Question regarding an electromechanical system of simplified capacitor microphone

Tags: control, electro-mechanical

[image]

The electromechanical system represents a simplified
model of a capacitor microphone. The system consists in part of a parallel
plate capacitor connected into an electric circuit. Capacitor plate a is
rigidly fastened to the microphone frame. Sound waves pass through the
mouthpiece and exert a force \$f_s(t)\$ on plate b. I am also given some formulas regarding the capacitor.
$$C(x)=\frac{\epsilon A}{x}$$
$$q=C(x)e$$
$$f_e=\frac{q^2}{2\epsilon A}$$

I have no idea how to solve the question and took a peak at the solution, then I get even more confused. From the solution I was given the free body equation of motion for plate M and that is
$$M\ddot{x}+ B\dot{x} + Kx + f_{e}sgn ( \dot{x}) = f_s (t)$$

Can anyone help me where the \$f_{e}sgn ( \dot{x})\$ comes from?

Comment: The $f_e \mathrm{sgn}(\dot{x})$ term looks like Coloumb friction

Comment: @Arnfinn but \$f_e\$ seems to depend on area and charge. Why would Coulomb friction depend on those values ? and not depend on some coefficient of friction ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source if available? There may be missing information in the question provided above.